# Lambda function being executed twice

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that has an API gateway Integration(Lamda API Gateway Proxy Integration). I know that if an error occurs, lambda tries to run again, but although there's no error(checked the cloudwatch logs), the lambda function is getting executed twice. I read a lot of documentation but I am not able to find a solution. Can anyone help me out

Comment: If you can't identify why your function is executed twice, can check `CloudTrial` to see what is invoking your lambda function. For that you need to enable `trial` to [log lambda invocations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-create-a-trail-using-the-console-first-time.html). API gateway does not invoke a function twice on errors (at least to my knowledge). Errors from lambda are relayed to the client.

Comment: I integrated cloudtrail with the lambda function, and the logs show it is being called from my side itself. But I am pretty sure it is being called only once from my side though(it's being called onClick). Any idea why?

Comment: I don't know what is `onClick`? Its part of your web application?

Comment: Yes, it's a web application and the function is being called on click of a button and I am sure this button is being clicked only once

Comment: To get more substantial help, you should provide more information, like the code of your AWS Lambda function and the code used to trigger it.

Comment: You can also setup API Gateway [logging for API calls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html). If your web app is calling the API twice, you should see two consecutive calls in the logs.